# Matlab - Using symbols in gscatter

Tags: colors, symbols, marker, scatter

Ok, so I'm trying to use gscatter to plot 8 different points in a figure. These 8 points are all different and thus I want to give them different symbols. I know that gscatter will automatically assign them different colors, but I also want to be able to use the figure in black and white. I have written the following code:

```
lincol = {'k';'k';'k';'k';'k';'k';'k';'k'};
linsym = {'+';'o';'*';'.';'x';'s';'d';'^'};
limits = [-1 1 -1 1];

close all

for i = 1:3;
figure(i); hold on
gscatter(RfootXdistpertRel(:,i),RfootYdistpertRel(:,i),lincol,linsym);
legend('Pert1', 'Pert2', 'Pert3', 'Pert4', 'Pert5', 'Pert6', 'Pert7', 'Pert8')
hline(0);
vline(0);
axis(limits);

end
```

According to the matlab syntax, I should be able to specify color and marker symbol in this way (gscatter(x,y,col,sym)). The variables used are 8 by 1 vectors, just as the lincol and linsym. However, it gives me an error:

```
Error using plot
Color value must be a 3 or 4 element vector
```

Can anyone help? It's just such a silly problem to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luc

It seems that you have some errors in your code. The syntax for gscatter should include at least 3 parameters : `x`, `y` and `group`. It seems that `group` is missing.
Furthermore the definition of `color` and `sym` may be wrong. Try `col = 'kkkkkkkk';` instead of `lincol = {'k';'k';'k';'k';'k';'k';'k';'k'};`.
I hope this helps.

Regards.

Jonay